# Sublime Text 3 files not opening in command line/powershell

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext3

I’ve just finished Codecademy and am setting up Python (2.7) and Sublime Text 3 on my own computer using the Codecademy guide page. I can successfully perform simple operations (eg. Print “Hello world”) a) in Python and b) by using ctrl+b on text in my Sublime Text 3 editor page, which gives the output in the box at the bottom of the page.

I’m stuck/confused when it comes to running the Sublime Text 3 file through the command line and confused on the powershell vs. command line issue (I’m running Windows 10).

My command line does not display the $ sign in the codecademy page example (https://www.codecademy.com/articles/setup-python), so should I be entering the commands below through Powershell rather than the command line? If so, I don’t get the $ in Powershell either.

If I carry on regardless and try to change directories etc through Command Prompt or Powershell, I only get error messages and can't seem to run the Sublime Text 3 file.

I’m also not clear on whether this is an issue about which directory I’m in. Running dir in both the Command prompt and Powershell returns the result:  after I’ve opened Python, but lists all subfolders of C:\Users\my_name if I run it before opening Python. Does this mean that I need to save my Sublime Text files in some sort of subfolder of Python in order to be able to run them as above?

Or does it not matter that I’m not able to run the Sublime Text 3 files through Python directly and I should just stick to doing so through Sublime Text 3 itself? Will this limit me later on?

Thanks for your help

BC89

Comment: The $ should be omitted, it only provides a hint that the command should be ran in a terminal. Any terminal(inside sublime or powershell) is fine.

Comment: Note also that it sounds like you're writing Python code, so apart from the fact that Sublime is the tool you're using to edit the files, they're still Python (i.e. they are not Sublime files; that has a different connotation, as if you are writing plugins for Sublime, for example)